# Serialize object to x-www-form-urlencoded with Feign and Jackson

Tags: java, post, jackson, netflix-feign

I am using netflix-feign with jackson to create a wrapper to the Mailgun API.
The problem is that the API requires the POST requests to be with `"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

This is a sample code:

```
@RequestLine("POST /messages")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
ResponseMessage sendMessage(Message message);
```

The `Message` object contains the necessary properties and they have JSON annotation: 
`@JsonProperty(value = "from")
 private String from;`

The problem is that the object that is send is a JSON object:

`{
  "from" : "test@test.mailgun.org",
  "to" : "atestaccount@gmail.com",
  "subject" : "A test email",
  "text" : "Hello this is the text of a test email.",
  "html" : "<html><body><h1>Hello this is the html of a test email.</h1></body></html>"
}`

This however is not a valid `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

Is there a way to automatically serialize the object to the correct content type?

I think that I can use the `@Body` annotation, but in order to use it I'll have to pass the different properties to the `sendMessage` method.

Answer (score 0):

#### Passing a String with xml content mapped

You could do it just sending an String in your method which have been parsed to xml before:

```
@RequestLine("POST /messages")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
ResponseMessage sendMessage(String message);
```

Then using a mapper (for example Jackson) you could map Message to xml:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
```

So then call the method with this xml:

```
sendMessage(xml);
```

#### Using an encoder

Otherwise, I think is possible configuring the encoder and decoder as you need. In this case to use XML you could use `JaxBEncoder` and `JaxBDecoder`:

```
api = Feign.builder()
              .encoder(new JAXBEncoder())
              .decoder(new JAXBDecoder())
              .target(Api.class, "https://apihost");
```